# Jenkins Creating HTML Reports But Link Broken

Tags: cucumber, jenkins, jenkins-plugins

When using Jenkins, it helpfully auto-generates a colorful report filled with all of your results from testing. The issue I'm having, however, is accessing that report.

I have all of my configuration set up the same as all of my other nodes. (I'm using master-slave configuration on Jenkins, with 4 slave node VMs running Win 7 x64.) When I open up Group 5, however, and open the HTML report page, I pick up the below error.

[image]

As always, any help is appreciated.

Comment: Add more information... show your configuration, what is the html you are trying to see?

Comment: Apologies for the lack of clarity. "Group 5" is a group of feature files and scenarios of automated tests run by cucumber. When run via Jenkins, it generates an HTML report, the HTML report exists, but it is unavailable in Jenkins, generating the above error.

Comment: The image is not showing up. Can you either copy-paste the error or type it in?

Comment: The image stated, 

"Status Code: 404

Exception:
Stacktrace:

(none)
_______________________________________
Generated by Winstone Servlet Engine v0.9.10 at Tue Jun 05 08:20:41 EDT 2012"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While I apologize for not being able to share any specifics of the error (configuration, etc. I'm under an NDA for that type of thing), I was able to solve my problem.

If you have everything set up for nodes, and are copying files back and forth between the Master and Slave (there's a plugin that allows you to copy files into the workspace before building instead of using an SCM) just don't have the post-build action of "Publish HTML Reports'" option of "Keep past HTML reports" checked. Otherwise you'll end up with file conflicts and you'll have the same 404 status code that I picked up.

Comment: I'm glad you solved your problem. One observation for the future: when answering people in comments include there handle with @ (e.g. @RazokKull), unless you are commenting on their answer. Otherwise they won't be notified of your comments. Good luck!

Comment: @malenkiy_scot Thanks for the tip! I had no idea that it was a feature.